# Determine if for all directed graphs $D$ the following relation R defined in $V (D)$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: graph-theory, equivalence-relations, directed-graphs

Determine if for all directed graphs D the following relation R defined in $V (D)$ is an equivalence relation: $xRy$ if and only if $x = y$ or there is an $xy$-path directed.

I don't seem to understand the $xy$ directed path.

I have an idea of how to prove reflexivity and maybe symetry.

But transitivity I don't have an idea

Comment: Suppose there is a directed path from $x$ to $y$ and a directed path from $y$ to $z$.  Now... take any such directed path from $x$ to $y$ and from $y$ to $z$ and concatenate the paths.  You now have a directed walk from $x$ to $z$.  (*Officially we need to be careful, this might not be a path because it could possibly have repeated edges if some edge or edges appeared in both paths involved in the concatenation.*)  Show that this then implies there is a directed path from $x$ to $z$ by removing any redundancies.

Comment: As for "proving symmetry"... a directed path existing from $x$ to $y$ does *not* imply that there is some directed path from $y$ to $x$.  Take a simple example with two vertices and only one edge going in a single direction.